# Is it possible to use Yeoman Angular generator with Yeoman Angular full stack organization?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I really like yeoman angular fullstack organization

```
client/app/myroute/myroute.js
client/app/myroute/myroute.controller.js
client/app/myroute/myroute.controller.spec.js
client/app/myroute/myroute.html
client/app/myroute/myroute.scss
```

Everything is in the same folder and it's easy to specify specific stylesheet codes.

My problem is I need to provide just an HTML static website, so yeoman angular generator seems to be more "appropriated". However it used an old fashioned organization. All controllers and all view in specific folders.

Do you know if it's possible to have the same kind of organisation in yeoman angular generator or use yeoman angular fullstack genrator without the server side ?

Thanks you in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the generator-cg-angular is exactly what you want.

https://github.com/cgross/generator-cg-angular